# I changed ManyToManyField relationship in ForeignKey, but now don't work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm new to Django and I have this problem: I want to create a simple web site where I display and work through the views objects Album and Artist. I changed the relationship

```
class Album(models.Model):
    ...
    songs_of_album = models.ManyToManyField('Song')

class Song(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

in my current models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='')
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    year = models.IntegerField(default=timezone.now().year)
    genre = models.ForeignKey('Genre',blank=False)
    vote = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,null=False,blank=False)
    album_name = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist')
    def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,primary_key=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to know two things:

- if my models.py is written right and the relationship that exists between the class and Album Artist
- Now when I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations` gives me this error  `You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to album without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
  Please select a fix:
  1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
  2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
  Select an option:`

I have read many posts similar but they are not able to find the solution.
I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: Did you try selecting one of those options?

Comment: You should set default value for database tables rows that existed, before you add new table during migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed m2m relationship to one2many, all is ok, but you need change your related database tables and you must migrate your db to new style, if you have any data on db set `null=True` for `album_name` attribute of `Song` class, and if your db is empty, delete all file in `migrations` folder of your app except `__init__.py` file, and then run two below commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

And then:

```
python manage.py migrate
```